# MySQL8 crash recovery from IBD files with import tablespace

Tags: mysql, import

Our database MySQL8 crashed due to no space left on the data directory. After we arranged more space the database kept crashing with the error

> [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: log0recv.cc:1948:!page
>   || (ibool) !!page_is_comp(page) == dict_table_is_comp(index->table)
>   thread 139625720006400

I know that there a lot of threads with this kind of issue. Believe me, I tried everything I could find, otherwise, I would not have opened this one.

I was only able to start it with recovery mode 6, but after that, it still does not start without recover mode. After an internet search, I tried many solutions but nothing worked.

At this point, I gave up trying to recover the DB and created a new DB with the same my.cnf hoping to import data from IBD files. I only changed the data directory from my.cnf file. Data directory from crashed DB was "/var/lib/mysql/sas/" the new DB has "/var/lib/mysql/sas/data/data/", with this I can move IBD files immediately. I cannot dump tables and import them to the new DB because the tables are too big and too many. It would take one month at least.

What I did was;

create table on the new DB
discard tablespace and move the IBD file to the new DB data directory
import tablespace
I am getting this error

> Page offset does not match file offset: page offset: 262144, file
>   offset: 262144

I can select the same table in the crashed DB opened with recovery mode 6. So I don't think that the IBD file is corrupt. Here I went out of ideas.

I am quite desperate at this point and any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Hi, Please provide full error message.

Comment: The error on import: 
https://ibb.co/DrPThM2
Part of the LOG:
https://gofile.io/?c=V8CUN3

I did not sent the whole LOG because it is too big of a file already.